# Выборка максимальных и минимальных значений по отношениям таблиц

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Проект на Laravel. Есть таблица orders, фильтр только дата. Мне надо к этой выборке добавить значение из относящейся таблицы `operations`(отношение один ко многим, в одном `order` может быть много `operations`): максимальное значение `procentage` по строкам с типом `penni`, минимальное значение `debt` по строкам с типом `credit`.
И так, в классе модели Order есть методы с отношениями

```
    public function operations(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Operation::class, 'order_id', 'id');
    }

    public function maxPercentage(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->operations()->one()->ofMany('percentage', 'max')
            ->where('type', 'penni');
    }

    public function initialCredit(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->operations()->one()->ofMany('debt', 'min')
            ->where('type', 'credit');
    }
```

`maxPercentage` и `initialCredit` методы добавил я, использую их при селекте из Order:

```
            $filtered = Order::filter($filter)
                ->with(['maxPercentage', 'initialCredit'])
                ->selectRaw('orders.*')
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
```

В итоге получаю ошибку

```
PDOException(code: 42883): SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function max(uuid) does not exist
LINE 1: ...perations\".* from \"operations\" inner join (select max(\"opera...
```

Подскажите, что я не так делаю. БД postgresql

Comment: судя по всему такая запись выбирает вам максимальный ключ связанной записи, а ключ у вас а-ля GUID. Если вам надо добавить только значение, то нельзя ли его подзапросом выбрать? А то тут похоже попытка вытащить всю строку с помощью джйонов.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно проверить работоспособность на ваших данных.

```php
    $filtered = Order::filter($filter)
                ->selectRaw('orders.*')
                ->selectRaw('MAX(o.percentage) as max_percentage')
                ->selectRaw('MIN(o.percentage) as min_percentage')
                ->join('operations as o', 'o.order_id', 'orders.id')
                ->groupBy('orders.id')
                ->limit($limit)
                ->get();
```